# "exports is not defined" when loading svg icon

Tags: webpack, reason, bucklescript, webpack-loader, svg-sprite

I'm using the `svg-sprite-loader` plug-in when trying to load an icon from an svg sprite file, however, the page fails with webpack error "exports is not defined". What could be happening? How can one debug webpack loaders like this and get more relevant error messages?

I followed [this](https://www.webdevdrops.com/build-an-svg-icon-component-with-react-de9db211ebd6/) tutorial except adapting for react.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Icon.bs.js:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at eval (Icon.bs.js:21)
    at Module../src/components/Icon/Icon.bs.js (Index.js:1357)
    at __webpack_require__ (Index.js:20)
    at eval (DebuggerTopBar.bs.js:6)
    at Object../src/components/DebuggerTopBar/DebuggerTopBar.bs.js (Index.js:1345)
    at __webpack_require__ (Index.js:20)
    at eval (Debugger.bs.js:6)
    at Object../src/components/Debugger/Debugger.bs.js (Index.js:1321)
    at __webpack_require__ (Index.js:20)
    at eval (Index.bs.js:15)
```

Here's all the code:

Component code

```
[%%raw "import '../../svg/icons.svg'"]; // this is the line that fails

[@react.component]
let make = (~name) =>
  <svg className={{j|icon icon-$name|j}}>
    <use xlinkHref={{j|#icons_$name|j}} />
  </svg>;
```

Which outputs this react code

```
// Generated by BUCKLESCRIPT, PLEASE EDIT WITH CARE
'use strict';

var React = require("react");

import '../../svg/icons.svg'
;

function Icon(Props) {
  var name = Props.name;
  return React.createElement("svg", {
              className: "icon icon-" + (String(name) + "")
            }, React.createElement("use", {
                  xlinkHref: "#icons_" + (String(name) + "")
                }));
}

var make = Icon;

exports.make = make;
/*  Not a pure module */
```

And the generated JS

```
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony import */ var _svg_icons_svg__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ../../svg/icons.svg */ "./src/svg/icons.svg");
// Generated by BUCKLESCRIPT, PLEASE EDIT WITH CARE


var React = __webpack_require__(/*! react */ "./node_modules/react/index.js");



function Icon(Props) {
  var name = Props.name;
  return React.createElement("svg", {
              className: "icon icon-" + (String(name) + "")
            }, React.createElement("use", {
                  xlinkHref: "#icons_" + (String(name) + "")
                }));
}

var make = Icon;

exports.make = make;
/*  Not a pure module */
```

Webpack config

```
  rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {  
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        loader: 'svg-sprite-loader'
      },
    ]
  }
```

Icon sprite file

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="locked" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <path d="M9 18h-2v14h2c0.55 0 1-0.45 1-1v-12c0-0.55-0.45-1-1-1z"></path>
      <path d="M23 18c-0.55 0-1 0.45-1 1v12c0 0.55 0.45 1 1 1h2v-14h-2z"></path>
      <path class="handles"
        d="M32 16c0-8.837-7.163-16-16-16s-16 7.163-16 16c0 1.919 0.338 3.759 0.958 5.464-0.609 1.038-0.958 2.246-0.958 3.536 0 3.526 2.608 6.443 6 6.929v-13.857c-0.997 0.143-1.927 0.495-2.742 1.012-0.168-0.835-0.258-1.699-0.258-2.584 0-7.18 5.82-13 13-13s13 5.82 13 13c0 0.885-0.088 1.749-0.257 2.584-0.816-0.517-1.745-0.87-2.743-1.013v13.858c3.392-0.485 6-3.402 6-6.929 0-1.29-0.349-2.498-0.958-3.536 0.62-1.705 0.958-3.545 0.958-5.465z"></path>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rob - fixed.

Comment: You should include the generated javascript.

Comment: Done now have the Reason -> React -> Webpack generated JS.

Comment: Just an educated guess, but you're mixing es6 and commonjs. `import` is es6, `require` is commonjs. You can either get bucklescript to emit es6, or change the `import` to `require`. You'll then probably also have to set the `esModule` option to `false`.

Comment: You're also not assigning the imported svg to any identifier. Not sure how that's supposed to work then.

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a Luddite, I'm not totally sure what this plugin is or how it works. Could you provide some background info? Then perhaps we can point you to a more idiomatic Reason way of doing it.

Comment: Not assigning the svg to an identifier is how it's meant to be used in the react tutorial. Thanks a lot for pointing out the commonjs/es6 dilemma, converting now to es6-global!

The purpose of this plug-in is to allow one to maintain an svg file of sprites (icons) and then be able to switch between them just by changing the id of the local svg component.

Comment: Changing to `es6-global` in `bsconfig` fixed things - do you mind submitting so I can accept as correct answer? Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately right now the SVG path is loaded and present in the DOM but not visible at all.

Comment: I've updated the question with this detail.

Comment: That's a different question, unrelated to most of the existing tags. You should post it as a separate question instead. Doing so will also get you a lot more attention. I'll roll your last edit back and formulate an answer from the comments here.

Comment: Posted new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57546347/svg-not-visible-svg-sprite-loader-webpack-reason-ml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you're mixing the es6 and commonjs module systems. `import` is es6 while `require` and the `exports` object is commonjs.

You'll have to either:

1. Move everything to es6. It is probably sufficient to just get BuckleScript to emit es6 by setting the [package-spec](https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/build-configuration#package-specs) to `es6-global` in bsconfig.json.
2. Move everything to commonjs. Change `import` to `require` and get `svg-sprite-loader` to emit commonjs by setting [`esModule`](https://github.com/kisenka/svg-sprite-loader#es-module) to `false` in its options in webpack config.